# Passing an object with an Exception?

Tags: python, exception

What is the correct way to pass an object with a custom exception?  I'm pretty sure this code *used* to work, but now it is throwing an error.

```
class FailedPostException(Exception):
    pass

def post_request(request):
    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.send(request.prepare(), timeout=5, verify=True)

    if response.status_code is not requests.codes.ok:
        raise FailedPostException(response)

    session.close()
    return response

try:
    ...
except FailedPostException as r:
    // type(r) - Requests.Response
    print r.text

AttributeError: 'FailedPostException' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: I think you can use `str(r)` instead of trying to make `r.text` work.

Comment: The proper way to comment a line in Python is using #, not //.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The raising and catching of the exception is correct, the issue here is that you expect the exception to have a `text` attribute that does not exist.  When inheriting from a built-in exception type you can use the `args` attribute, which will be a tuple of the arguments to the exception, for example:

```
try:
    ...
except FailedPostException as r:
    print r.args[0]
```

In this case you could use `str(r)` instead of `r.args[0]`.  If there is only one argument to the exception then `str(r)` will be equivalent to `str(r.args[0])`, otherwise it will be equivalent to `str(r.args)`.

If you want to add the `text` attribute to your `FailedPostException`, you can do the following:

```
class FailedPostException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, text, *args):
        super(FailedPostException, self).__init__(text, *args)
        self.text = text
```

Note that in Python 3.x you can just use `super().__init__(text, *args)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep a reference to the original `Response` object and expose its attributes like this:

```
class FailedPostException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, rsp):
        super(FailedPostException, self).__init__()
        self.response = rsp
    @property
    def text(self):
        return self.response.text
    @property
    def status_code(self):
        return self.response.status_code
    #other properties if interested....
```

In case you need to introspect more of the `Response` object

```
r.response.url
r.response.reason
...
```

Answer (score 1):

An exception is just another type of object:

```
class FailedPostException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, text):
        Exception.__init__(self, text)
        self.text = text
```

That should make the response available as `.text`